# 500 internal server error with WAMP on my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, internal-server-error

Yesterday as I was "messing up" with the links in the general settings of my wordpress site I found myself in front of the 500 internal server error message and I panicked since I never saw something like this before. After extended research I found out that the exact problem is this:

```
[core:error] [pid 9876:tid 1316] [client ::1:64092] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://localhost/eshop/wp-admin/options-general.php
```

and that my .htaccess contains this:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /eshop/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /eshop/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

Since I am not a developer all these are a bit foreign to me and I do not how to deal with them. Any help would be really appreciated because I have no idea how to access my site since yesterday.

Thank you in advance,
Fani

Answer (score 0):

If you moved the WP install to a folder then editing your wp-config.php file will be the safest if you are not a dev
Define your WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL settings by inserting these lines towards the top:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com/folder/');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com/folder/');
```